# I would like to combine the duplicate values in Elasticsearch into one and see the results with a different filter

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, distinct

I'm collecting logs through Elastic Search. The logs are collected as below.

```
ex.
{
"name" : "John"
"team" : "IT"
"startTime" : "21:00"
"result" : "pass"
},
{
"name" : "James"
"team" : "HR"
"startTime" : "21:04"
"result" : "pass"
},
{
"name" : "Paul"
"team" : "IT"
"startTime" : "21:05"
"result" : "pass"
},
{
"name" : "Jackson"
"team" : "Marketing"
"startTime" : "21:30"
"result" : "fail"
},
{
"name" : "John"
"team" : "IT"
"startTime" : "21:41"
"result" : "pass"
},

.....and so on
```

If you run the query below on these collected logs,

```
GET logData/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "Documents_per_team": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "team"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following results will be exposed.

```
"aggregations" : {
    "Documents_per_team" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "IT",
          "doc_count" : 70
        },
        {
          "key" : "Marketing",
          "doc_count" : 55
        },
        {
          "key" : "HR",
          "doc_count" : 11
         }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to eliminate duplication if the name of the document is duplicated in this result.

[AS-IS]

- As shown above, the IT team count is exposed to 70

[The result I want]

- if John performed 50 times, Kate performed 10 times, Paul performed 10 times, the IT team count 3 is exposed. (Because there are three of IT team member)

Can I get a team-by-team result after removing duplicates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options:

1. a [cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_script_4) sub-aggregation (**straightforward**, but *[approximate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_counts_are_approximate) and not very scalable, albeit only in very specific/advanced situations*)
2. or a [scripted metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation (*slower, more verbose but **exact***).

Both approaches assume that the `name`s are unique per team-level. If they're not, you'll need to [adjust accordingly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_script_4). Also, it is assumed that the `name` is mapped to be of type `keyword`, just like the `team`. If not, you'll need to replace them with `your_field.keyword`

### 1. Cardinality

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Documents_per_team": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "team"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_names_per_team": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### 2. Scripted Metric

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Documents_per_team": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.by_department = [:]; state.dept_vs_name = [:];",
        "map_script": """
          def dept = doc['team'].value;
          def name = doc['name'].value;
          
          def name_already_considered = state.by_department.containsKey(dept) && state.dept_vs_name[dept].containsKey(name);
          
          if (name_already_considered) {
            return;
          }
          
          if (state.by_department.containsKey(dept)) {
            state.by_department[dept] += 1;
          } else {
            state.by_department[dept] = 1
          }
          
          if (!state.dept_vs_name.containsKey(dept)) {
            // init new map & set is first member
            state.dept_vs_name[dept] = [name:true];
          } else if (!state.dept_vs_name[dept].containsKey(name)) {
            state.dept_vs_name[dept][name] = true;
          }
        """,
        "combine_script": "return state.by_department",
        "reduce_script": "return states"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Note**: If you also wish to see the underlying dept vs. name breakdown, you can modify the `combine_script` to return the whole state, i.e. `return state`.*